# Typechecking in gcc macros and type decay

Tags: c, gcc, macros

This:

```
#define MC_tpchk(X,Y) \
    ({  __typeof(X) _x; __typeof(Y) _y; (void)(&_x == &_y);  1; })
```

is stolen (with renames) from the Linux source.
I'd like to use it to typecheck some stuff in some of my generic macros (can't use inline functions there).

Unfortunately, it has some issues with string literals:

This all works:

```
char c_a, c_b;
int i_a, i_b;
char *s_a, *s_b;
MC_tpchk(c_a,c_b);
MC_tpchk(i_a,i_b);
MC_tpchk(s_a,s_b);
char *foo = "foo";
MC_tpchk(s_a,foo);
```

But this is a compile error:

```
MC_tpchk(s_a, "foo");
```

The error:

```
error: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [-Werror]
```

is just a warning if I compile without `-Werror`, but I would like to keep the `-Werror` there.

How else can I deal with this error?

My guess is that the detected type is probably `char[]`. How can I make the compiler show this? Can I make the macro arguments decay (in this case to `char*`) so this is no longer an error?

Comment: This is a really good question. Could it be that the compiler is optimizing `foo` to be a `const char*` sense it detects no modifications to the pointer?

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar I don't think so. You can add a `char const *bar="bar";` and it typechecks with `char *foo="foo";` just fine as `char const **` is comparable to `char **`.

Comment: Does the same error occur with `const char *s_a; const char *foo = "foo";
MC_tpchk(s_a,foo);`?  (Can not test that on my machine.)  IOWs is the problem a `const` one or a `char *` vs `char[]` one?

Comment: @chux: It doesn't seem to be a `const` issue from the error message I produced. But, I don't have a C.2011 compliant compiler to test against.

Comment: @jxh Note: C11 does not have `__typeof` so a compliant C11 compiler is not needed to test.

Comment: @chux: Re-read the standard. String literals are `char *`s for which modification results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @jxh How does "String literals are char *s for which modification results in UB" (which is certainly true) apply to OP's macro, OP's post or to `__typeof`.  No attempt to modify the string literal is occurring in OP's code. `char *foo = "foo";` is certainly not UB.

Comment: @chux: I just meant that string literals are not made up of `const char`, but regular `char` that cannot be modified.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131093/discussion-between-chux-and-jxh).

Comment: @chux It was a [] vs * issue. I think qualifiers are irrelevant in the Linux typecheck macro as it compares addresses.

Comment: @Agree it is a [] vs * issue.  Yet `const` can [impact the code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41252226/2410359) too.  Hence my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250083/typechecking-in-gcc-macros-and-type-decay/41252226#comment69702056_41250083) to delve into that aspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does appear to be because the string literal is being detected as an array type. A pointer to an array type does not match a pointer to a pointer type.

I wrote a different macro:

```
#define MC_tpchk(X,Y) \
    do { \
        break; \
        void (*CHK) (__typeof(X) *); \
        __typeof(Y) _y; \
        CHK(&_y); \
    } while (0)
```

This seems to provide a more descriptive error:

`error: passing argument 1 of 'CHK' from incompatible pointer type`
`note: expected 'const char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[4]'`

I can't think of a way to decay the array within the macro to properly detect its compatibility with a pointer type. However, the caller of your macro could be conditioned to handle an array differently. So, this would work:

```
MC_tpchk(s_a, &*"foo");
```

Comment: I think `do{ break; void (*chk)(__typeof(X) ); __typeof(Y) _y; chk(_y); }while(0)`  (without the extra * and &) does what I want -- namely answer whether Y can be assigned to X. I don't really understand what the & were there for, tbh.

Comment: I tried this macro with the 4 variable types in my answer as `MC_tpchk(var, &*"foo");` and `MC_tpchk(var, "foo");` and receive warnings like "[-Wincompatible-pointer-types]" in 5 of 8 cases.  Still a good answer.

Comment: @chux I tested the modified version (as in my comment) of jxh's answer with a couple of examples and it gives me errors exactly where I wanted them. It's not a perfect accept, but the idea of using function arguments to decay the poitner helped. (I appreciate your answer too.)

Comment: @PSkocik Glad this answer works for you.   The original `MC_tpchk()` is picky, perhaps too picky for your code.  Yet this good answer and other variations are simply trying to defeat the check, a little bit, in various select ways.  These little deviations may be acceptable where you (and likely many)  want them, but are unacceptable for broad general use.  Good question though.